# Update the DB table by taking user input from SSRS front end

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2017

I would like to update the DB table by taking user input from SSRS front end.And then, when I click generate report, this should get the user input values from DB table (that were previously updated in DB) and render/display in the same report body. 
Ref: https://github.com/JerBoon/updating_with_SSRS

Here is how I'm trying to achieve this:

1. Created 2 parameters for user to input the text.
2. In DataSet4, I'm writing update query to update the DB.
   [image]
3. No errors
4. report preview.
   [image]

5.Here is the table structure that needs to be updated:
[image]

```
USE [AdventureWorks2017]
 GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WIP](
[WIPID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Cata] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Cout] [int] NULL,
[Remark] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Ack] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_WIP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [WIPID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
  OFF, 
  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

However, the problem is : I'm unable to update the table and also unable to render those inputted by user. Below image:
[image]

The user input should have been rendered, which is not. Hope I explained this correctly. What am I doing wrong?

I would like to achieve this in a single report. That is, same report should be used for user input and display that were inputted by user. How can I achieve this in SSRS 2016/2017? Unable to find something suitable over the net. It looks like there are 3rd party tools used, However, I would like to do this using SSRS in build feature.Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to take the values, store them, and then run a query based on those stored values? Why not just use a parametrised query? Then there's no need to store them.

Comment: I understood. However, I need to store them as it may be required in the future.

Comment: What would be, knowing what parameters the user passed? This, as it stands, sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: Modified the question. I'm able to clear the error now. However, the update statement is not updating the table.

Comment: *"However, the update statement is not updating the table."* This is impossible for us to trounle shoot without being able to replicate the problem. Best guess, your `UPDATE` statement is wrong.

Comment: Anyways, used SP to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: The original problem was that you had declared the parameters in your dataset query. If you had commented out the 2 declare statements it would work assuming the names in the UPDATE statement matched the name of the SSRS parameter exactly (case sensitive)

Comment: As Alan mentioned, your update statements was declaring it's own parameters and was SETting your values to NULL since you don't have the SSRS parameters mapped to the query's parameters.